# Can you resize all text in a Photoshop file at once?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have created a design in Photoshop on 1170px grid. When I tried to convert to HTML I released that everything looks very big. Is there any short method to resize all fonts and images with some % in Photoshop without effecting resolution.

Comment: Are you automatically converting to HTML? I would try by all means to avoid automating this process. You can export your images using Photoshop, but if you want an error-free site, you need to write your own code. It's the only way to guarantee things will work well.

Comment: `Image > Image Size` will allow reduction (or enlargement) via percentages. This is document-wide however.

Comment: This is a confusing question. You can resize items, of course, but that, in turn, would obviously affect resolution. All that said, you shouldn't be exporting text as images anyways. That should be done with HTML--not PhotoShop.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [SiteGrinder 3](http://www.medialab.com/sitegrinder3/featuretour.php). It is a PSD to HTML conversion software. Have used it a few times myself.

Comment: I'm uncertain how this link-only answer *actually* answers the question.